# Using Interfaces in JNI

Tags: java, interface, callback, java-native-interface

I am trying to use `(*env)->RegisterNatives` to add methods to a defined class which I then add to a callback list.
The callback sender of course expects my class to implement a certain interface which I do not. And is failing on execution.

If I add the keyword "implements Listener" to my class in Java the javac expects to have the methods definition in Java or with native keyword which I try to avoid here, as I'd like to register the methods within the JNI_OnLoad and execute one of them afterwards.

The question now is: Can I implement the interface in JNI or avoid the error message in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterNatives` doesn't add new native methods, it registers native function for the existing native method in the class. If someone doesn't call RegisterNatives for a native method, the `JVM` will search all `DLL` libraries for its implementation when method is called for the first time.

So, add `implements Listener`, write definitions with `native` keyword and register their implementation with `RegisterNatives`.

Comment: Thank you. If you hadn't pointed me to my misunderstanding with the RegisterNatives it would have taken me another week at least.